# Add Linear Layout and Imageview Via code to it with proper alignment

Tags: android

I am trying to add a linear layout and three Imageview as its children properly aligned,via code.Any help in this case will be helpfull.I have been trying various strategies which didn't work out.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: Please do share your strategies.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
layout.addView(imageview);
```

Try Like this..